# making an angular app modular while keeping index.html clean

Tags: angularjs, architecture

I am building a large scale enterprise angularjs application.  I have studied hard and used countless hours to make sure that the architecture is modular and non dependent!

Because of this my application is going to contain alot of different modules each of these modules will contain

- Directives
- Services / Factories
- configuration files

And more.

However  there is one problem that i cannot seem to get my head around!

Say you have two modules with two directives in each then in your index.html file you would have the following:

```
<script src="js/modules/module1/module1.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/module1/directives/module1directive1.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/module1/directives/module1directive2.js"></script>

<script src="js/modules/module2/module2.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/module2/directives/module2directive1.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/module2/directives/module2directive2.js"></script>
```

This is "sort of" okay however once the number of directives and module rise the load time rises also it will be hard to keep track of all of these files

(as you well know some modules are dependent on each other and has to be loaded in the correct order).

Since we already know that `module1directive1` is a directive that is directly used only when `module1` is active i was hoping that there is a way to only include this when needed?

a sort of import if you will. Seeing as this directive / service or other cannot be used while the module it belongs to is not active.

I am guessing i am not the first with this problem. But sadly i haven't been able to find anyone who addresses this issue.

Comment: Have you tried using something like grunt to combine your source into a single file?

Comment: @Ankh yeah i have and it could work however it wouldnt negate the tedious task of having to put all the scripts into my index.html

Comment: Why wouldn't it? You merge all your source into a single file, myApp.js or whatever, then include **one** script tag in your index.html for the merged file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use john papa aproach to handle angular application 
here the link of [john papa angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)